# Keras LSTM not training

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, data-science

I have an LSTM whose output is the same across the board. How could I go about fixing this? The following are the parameters. I'd love to have a general answer as this would help me learn the solution in case I see it again.

```
batch_size = 32
X_train.shape, Y_train.shape, X_test.shape, Y_test.shape
>((1920, 30, 5), (1920, 6), (1696, 30, 5), (1696, 6))

data_dim = X_train.shape[2]
timesteps = X_train.shape[1]

# Expected input batch shape: (batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)
# Note that we have to provide the full batch_input_shape since the network is stateful.
# the sample of index i in batch k is the follow-up for the sample i in batch k-1.

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, 
               return_sequences=True, 
               stateful=True,
               kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001),
               batch_input_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, 
               kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001), 
               stateful=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(LSTM(32, stateful=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax', use_bias=True))

rms = RMSprop(lr=0.001)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=rms,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
              batch_size=batch_size, 
              epochs=5, 
              shuffle=False,
              validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

After training, I get the following output:

```
0b  1b  2b  3b  4b  5b                          
2017-06-30  0.077203    0.180573    0.314528    0.287455    0.110213    0.030026    
2017-07-03  0.077225    0.180570    0.314542    0.287430    0.110204    0.030029    
2017-07-04  0.077220    0.180586    0.314541    0.287423    0.110207    0.030023    
2017-07-05  0.077193    0.180622    0.314523    0.287426    0.110221    0.030015    
2017-07-06  0.077125    0.180695    0.314496    0.287435    0.110257    0.029992
```

They're all very very similar :(

EDIT: Forgot to mention I used the sklearn MinMaxScaler and scaled the data to (-7,7) as that seemed to have worked in the past. Is this a right approach?

Comment: Any particular reason you chose -7 and 7? Maybe try scaling between 0 and 1.

Comment: No particular reason other than it having worked on previous data sets. 0, 1 also produces similar results :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry; it's a **common problem**, to solve it you have to find optimum parameters for your network.

Unfortunately, I can't tell you how to fix your aNN but here are some ideas, which you can try:

- change the activation function to ELU or ReLu
- remove dropouts and add batch normalization
- change number of layers (try to be as small as possible)
- increase the batch size
- decrease the regularization coefficient
- @jdehesa suggested to train longer
- add more data ...

Comment: Also, I'd add just train longer. In my experience, RNNs take longer than other models to start to produce something resembling to useful outputs.

Comment: ELU and ReLu are activation functions not optimizers. But trying different optimizier is not a bad advice either (despite rmsprop being pretty popular in LSTMS).

Comment: @jdehsa if I train it longer, it may come out of the 'pit'?